# the phonegap directory structure in apache php

Tags: php, apache, cordova

I am sorry for this such question as I am still a fresh beginner in Phonegap. 
I have followed some tutorial both for the installation and the jquery.mobile usage.

There are some parts (the biggest part) that I am confused with this Phonegap. And it is about the directory structure.

I am working with *Private* PHP Framework from my department, that is why I used Lamp Stack for all of this.

However, with the Phonegap tutorials I have been following this far, it looks like it have a little bit different environment structure from usual. It have five default directory as follows:

- Hook
- platforms
- Plugins
- www

In where the working directory for this Phonegap must be in the www directory.

It makes me afraid because our Apache Environment require us to put the directory in costume folder (Not in var/www), and then also the PHP Framework require us to put the module in a specific folder.

Please, I just need an enlightment for this Phonegap, how do you access the files and where do you guys put it.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to tests your site locally in an apache env, the vhost should point to www

Comment: We cant point our vhost to www. Please help.

Comment: Our Vhost points to **kunder** (probably custom directory)

Comment: Then I guess you would have to use a symbolick link. You could also create another vhost just for the www

Comment: Symbolik link in where, could you please describe it more?

Comment: Just create another vhost...

Comment: OK, if I must point my vhost to www directory, then how about the five default directory from the phonegap, where I should put each of the directory. Please help.

Comment: Please, make it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of cordova/phonegap is simple. Inside the www folder will be all your programming logic to build yours mobile app.

But beware, the cordova/phonegap does not compile code in PHP, it just uses a webview (like a browser) to run your mobile application developed with HTML, CSS and Javascript, packaged in a apk with access to native features of the smartphone/tablet, basically.

To make your application to communicate to the server in php you have two alternatives:

> 1) Making your app to access a URL that points to the application
>   developed with PHP and render its application in webview.
>
> 2) Create all purely on HTML, CSS and Javascript and make
>   communication via ajax, or socket or something similar to the server.

Comment: I accept it without vote it up because you late answer it before I have already caught it by myself. Anyway, thank you, you just ensure my own discovery. Beneficial. :)

Answer (score 1):

As requested:
Create another vhost that points to www. You don't need to worry about hook, platform and plugins which are cordova/phonegap folders. Let them all at the same level (don't change the structure, just point the vhost to www).

Comment: Please edit, why shouldn't I need to worry about the hook, platform, and plugin. Thanks.

Comment: Where I should put the rest.

Comment: I just told you where. Just leave everything at the same level.

Comment: OK, thanks. I just vote it up for a moment. Will accept it when I am done testing.

Comment: Still confuse. Of course in www directory, people will have multiple webs folder. But, the www in the phonegap directly distribute the child folders.

Comment: "But, the www in the phonegap directly distribute the child folders" I don't know what you mean by that

Comment: the folder of css, js, img and etc.

Comment: put them anywhere you want inside www